# generic deserialisation (type-punning) of structs (fighting with the borrow checker)

Tags: rust

I am using packed structs and I need to be able to go from raw
bytes to structs and vice versa without any decoding/encoding overhead.

I wrote some code that seemed to work:

```
#[packed]
struct Test {
    data: u64
}
impl Test {
    fn from_byte_slice(bs: &[u8]) -> Option<Test> {
        if bs.len() != std::mem::size_of::<Test>() {
            None
        } else {
            let p: *const u8 = &bs[0];
            let p2: *const Test = p as *const Test;
            unsafe {
                Some(*p2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I have a couple of different structs that need to be serialized/deserialed
so I wanted to use a generic function to reduce code duplication.

The following code fails to compile with the error message: "error: cannot move out of dereference of `*`-pointer"

```
fn from_byte_slice<T>(bs: &[u8]) -> Option<T> {
    if bs.len() != std::mem::size_of::<T>() {
        None
    } else {
        let p: *const u8 = &bs[0];
        let p2: *const T = p as *const T;
        unsafe {
            Some(*p2)
        }
    }
}
```

What is weird is that if I instead of returning an Option return an Option<&T> then the code compiles:

```
fn from_byte_slice<'a, T>(bs: &'a [u8]) -> Option<&'a T> {
    if bs.len() != std::mem::size_of::<T>() {
        None
    } else {
        let p: *const u8 = &bs[0];
        let p2: *const T = p as *const T;
        unsafe {
            Some(&*p2)
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or have I run into a bug in the borrow checker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument `bs: &[u8]` is a slice, and is *borrowed*. This is a form of temporary ownership, you can't move the data out. `*p2` does just that, it moves ownership of that data out.

You need to clone it:

```
fn from_byte_slice<T: Clone>(bs: &[u8]) -> Option<T> {
    if bs.len() != std::mem::size_of::<T>() {
        None
    } else {
        let p: *const u8 = &bs[0];
        let p2: *const T = p as *const T;
        unsafe {
            Some((*p2).clone())
        }
    }
}
```

Using `transmute` you probably can make this work with a `Vec<u8>` instead, if you don't mind moving an owned vector into the function.

The direct impl in the first case works because `Test` contains all `Copy` fields and is thus implicitly copied (instead of needing the explicit `clone()`).

This [probably will change soon](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/17864), `Copy` will have to be explicitly derived in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution seems to work. However, why does the first (non-generic) solution work as well? I believe the logic is exactly the same, but the borrow checker doesn't complain about it.

Comment: @danvari because you just reborrowed it. You can reborrow borrowed data, converting it to another `&` pointer of the same or smaller lifetime, but you can't convert borrowed data to owned data without an explicit copy.

Comment: You're talking about the last solution, I'm asking why the first code sample worked, I don't believe there is any reborrowing in that sample.

Comment: @danvari, the first sample worked because `Test` automatically implements `Copy` kind, that is, it is implicitly copyable (because of its simple contents). `Copy` types are copied, not moved, so you can easily write `*t` anywhere - the original value will be left intact.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: That's not it either. The actual struct in my program is a much larger and more complicated struct with a lot of different fields. I just simplified it for the stackoverflow question.

Comment: @danvari, It does not really matter when all fields are `Copy`. Just check it - if no field has a destructor or is a mutable reference, then the struct will be `Copy` regardless of its size and the number of fields.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: You are right, and that was the solution to my problem. Just define the function as from_byte_slice<T: Copy>(...). Do you want to write it up as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @danvari Sorry, I'd forgotten about the first example. Updated the answer

Comment: @danvari, in fact, I'd suggest you adding `#[deriving(Clone)]` on your structs and go with @Manishearth's answer and use `T: Clone` with explicit `clone()` call. This would make your method much more generic, as it would be possible to use it with non-`Copy` types like `Vec<T>`.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: I believe that would be the right solution, however my structs have fixed-length vectors in them ([u8, ..255]) and #[deriving(Clone)] does not work for structs containing fixed-length vectors. I think I need to ask another question for that though.

Comment: @danvari That's [this bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/7622). You can work around it with something like [this](http://is.gd/5f1xhq)